# How can I copy files from multiple folders using the Windows command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I have `txt` files in multiple folders: (folder_1, folder_2 . . . folder_n).

I would like to copy all these files into another directory using the Windows command line.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How would you like conflicting filenames to be handled? Ignored (skipped)? Overwritten? Abort the copy operation? Could you provide an example (list some sample source file paths and same destination file paths)?

Comment: Would the answers to [this](http://superuser.com/q/390677/117590) question help? They handle conflicting filenames.

Comment: Also see [batch file Copy files with certain extensions from multiple directories into one directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224880/batch-file-copy-files-with-certain-extensions-from-multiple-directories-into-one).

Answer (score 1):

you can try it using a batch file
place all the copy commands that you need into the batch file, for example

```
copy <path1>\file*.txt <destination> 
copy <path2>\file*.txt <destination>
```

and so on as many times as you need. Then run the batch file
Create the batch file in notepad and save with the .bat extension

Answer (score 0):

Copying multiple files

1. Using the cd command, move to the directory that contains the files you wish to copy.
2. Once in the directory that contains the files you wish to copy, type a command similar to one of the below commands.

copy *.* c:\mydir

In the above example, the command would copy every file in the current directory to the "mydir" directory.

copy *.txt c:\mydir

In the above example, the command would copy every txt, or text file, in the current directory into the "mydir" directory.

Comment: The question is asking about copying files from multiple folders. Unless you are recommending manually changing to each directory before copying, this does not answer the question. And the question implies a large number of directories where manual switching is far from optional.

Comment: I apologize if I am wrong answer just to answer what I understand